# Spreadsheetgear replace formula with it's result

Tags: c#, .net, spreadsheetgear

I am using spreadsheetgear 2012 for c# .net excel manipulation purpose. I have some excel formulas in some of the cells. Now I want to replace the formula in the excel with the evaluated number. Is there any particular way to do this? Tried searching the spreadsheetgear forum but didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be accomplished a couple different ways:

- Set IRange.[Value](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Value.html) to itself for the desired range.  IRange.[Formula](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Formula.html) contains a cell's formula and IRange.[Value](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Value.html) the calculated value.  Setting IRange.[Value](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Value.html) to itself will effectively remove the formula from the cell and leave only the value.  This will work on a single cell and also on a multi-cell range (since IRange.[Value](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Value.html) can return a object[,] array and can also be set from an object[,] array).
- Use IRange.[Copy](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Copy.html)(...) method with the [PasteType](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017~SpreadsheetGear.PasteType.html).Values option on the desired range, which is the equivalent of doing a Paste Special > Values in Microsoft Excel.

Below are examples of these approaches:

```
using SpreadsheetGear;
...

// Create workbook and some local variables.
IWorkbook workbook = Factory.GetWorkbook();
IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveWorksheet;
IRange cells = worksheet.Cells;

// EXAMPLE 1 - IRange.Value with single cell
// Set A1 to a formula and output some info about A1's contents.
IRange a1 = cells["A1"];
a1.Formula = "=ROUND(RAND(),2)";
Console.WriteLine($"{a1.Address}: HasFormula={a1.HasFormula}, Formula='{a1.Formula}', Value={a1.Value}");
// OUTPUT: $A$1: HasFormula=True, Formula='=ROUND(RAND(),2)', Value=0.69
// Set IRange.Value to itself
a1.Value = a1.Value;
Console.WriteLine($"{a1.Address}: HasFormula={a1.HasFormula}, Formula='{a1.Formula}', Value={a1.Value}");
// OUTPUT: $A$1: HasFormula=False, Formula='0.69', Value=0.69


// EXAMPLE 2 - IRange.Value with multiple cells
// Works on multiple cells since IRange.Value will return an object[,]
// array for a range representing multiple cells.
IRange b1b3 = cells["B1:B3"];
b1b3.Formula = "=ROUND(RAND(),2)";
foreach (IRange cell in b1b3)
    Console.WriteLine($"{cell.Address}: HasFormula={cell.HasFormula}, Formula='{cell.Formula}', Value={cell.Value}");
// OUTPUT:
// $B$1: HasFormula=True, Formula='=ROUND(RAND(),2)', Value=0.81
// $B$2: HasFormula=True, Formula='=ROUND(RAND(),2)', Value=0.55
// $B$3: HasFormula=True, Formula='=ROUND(RAND(),2)', Value=0.24

// Set IRange.Value to itself (2D object[,] used)
b1b3.Value = b1b3.Value;
foreach (IRange cell in b1b3)
    Console.WriteLine($"{cell.Address}: HasFormula={cell.HasFormula}, Formula='{cell.Formula}', Value={cell.Value}");
// OUTPUT:
// $B$1: HasFormula=False, Formula='0.81', Value=0.81
// $B$2: HasFormula=False, Formula='0.55', Value=0.55
// $B$3: HasFormula=False, Formula='0.24', Value=0.24


// EXAMPLE 3 - IRange.Copy() with PasteType.Values option
IRange c1c2 = cells["C1:C2"];
c1c2.Formula = "=ROUND(RAND(),2)";
foreach (IRange cell in c1c2)
    Console.WriteLine($"{cell.Address}: HasFormula={cell.HasFormula}, Formula='{cell.Formula}', Value={cell.Value}");
// OUTPUT:
// $C$1: HasFormula=True, Formula='=ROUND(RAND(),2)', Value=0.04
// $C$2: HasFormula=True, Formula='=ROUND(RAND(),2)', Value=0.14

c1c2.Copy(c1c2, PasteType.Values, PasteOperation.None, false, false);
foreach (IRange cell in c1c2)
    Console.WriteLine($"{cell.Address}: HasFormula={cell.HasFormula}, Formula='{cell.Formula}', Value={cell.Value}");
// OUTPUT:
// $C$1: HasFormula=False, Formula='0.04', Value=0.04
// $C$2: HasFormula=False, Formula='0.14', Value=0.14
```

Comment: EXAMPLE 3 - IRange.Copy() works with single cell but does not work with merged cells. 
Any idea or known bug ?

Comment: For merged cells, IRange.Copy() throws error InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid for a partial merged cell.

Comment: @VirajSanghavi - see my response to your new question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58434455/233365